# dtype='numeric' is not compatible with arrays of bytes/strings.Convert your data to numeric values explicitly instead

Tags: scikit-learn, reshape, roc

I have these data I want to use for a logistic regression problem. shape of the data:

```
((108, 2),##train input
 (108,),##train output
 (35, 2), ##val input
 (35,),##val output
 (28, 2),##test input
 (28,),##test output
 (171, 3), ## all data
```

I did this:

```
'''
X = X_train.reshape(-2,2)
y = y_train.reshape(-1,1)
model_lr = LogisticRegression()
res = model_lr.fit(X,y)
X_test = np.array(X_test,dtype = float)
test = X_test.reshape(-2,2)
test = np.array(test,dtype = float)
pred = model_lr.predict(test)
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve

output_test = y_test.reshape(-1,1)
output_test = np.array(output_test,dtype = float)


logit_roc_auc = roc_auc_score(output_test, model_lr.predict(test))

'''
```

and I have this error message:

```
logit_roc_auc = roc_auc_score(output_test, model_lr.predict(test))
```

```
ValueError: dtype='numeric' is not compatible with arrays of bytes/strings.Convert your data to numeric values explicitly instead.
```

can anybody help?
thanks

I tried reshaping the output variable, but I didn't succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`roc_auc_score` should be able to handle an array of strings. But computing an ROC curve generally requires `y_pred` to be an array of floats.

Print your `output_test` and `model_lr.predict(test)` and make sure they look like the following—you'll probably see you need to switch to `model_lr.predict_proba(test)`:

```py
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

y_true = ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"]
y_pred = [0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 0.4, 0.7, 0.8]

print(roc_auc_score(y_true, y_pred))
# 0.8888
```